# git fetch keeps failing

Tags: git, tfs, cmd, branch

I created a branch on Ms TFS and I tried to pull it on to my local machine with the code:

```
git fetch
```

This is the result of the fetch:

```
error: cannot update the ref 'refs/remotes/origin/tryYourself/192RestService': unable to create directory for '.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/tryYourself/192RestService': No such file or directory
From "url"
 ! [new branch]      tryYourself/192RestService -> origin/tryYourself/192RestService  (unable to update local ref)
```

Then I searched it on Google and StackOverflow, and they told me to do:

```
git gc --prune=now
```

And also:

```
git remote prune origin
```

Then I did again:

```
git fetch
```

So I can work on that branch but it gives back the result/error as above.

Someone has some advice?

Comment: Did you checked .git folder and sudbfolders permission ?

Comment: yeah that is all good ...

Comment: What if you clone repo in a new folder ?

Comment: stil gives error

Comment: (A) are you on a case-folding system (e.g., Mac or Windows); (B) what goes `git ls-remote origin` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the user run the `git fetch` has the write permission to
   your local repository.
2. Please check if there is a file called **"192RestService"** under
   `refs/remotes/origin/tryYourself/`
3. Try to **remove** the file **"192RestService"**, then check the `gitfetch` again.

Comment: @HomeForce Have you resolved your issue by above workaround?

Answer (score 0):

try the below steps if `git fetch` or `git fetch --all` is not working

Steps:

1. Run `vi .git/config` command in the project directory.
2. search for this line of code

> [remote "origin"]

3. Mention this code under [remote "origin"] and Save

> fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Your final code will look like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:fadiahac/seo-manager.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Done!! ✅