# Git: error: cannot lock ref while Get Sources in VSTS git build

Tags: git, azure-devops

While I am trying to run my build through VSTS Git I am getting the following error:

**error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/x/y': 'refs/remotes/origin/x' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/x/y'**

**![new branch] x/y -> origin/x/y (unable to update local references)**

***error: some local refs could not be updated; try running
'git remote prune origin' to remove any old, conflicting branches***

I have tried pruning and did whatever could have done but still the issue persists. Please help

Comment: Can any suggestion from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998832/git-pull-fails-unable-to-resolve-reference-unable-to-update-local-ref) turn out to be helpful? Also, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44819325/git-fetch-keeps-failing) was asked specifically about VSTS and contains a workaround which might help, too.

Comment: What's the command(s) did you execute? And does the command(s) run during VSTS build?